# Formatting Java enums using one line for every enum value with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, formatting

I have a Java code like this:

```
private enum Operation {
        SAVE, LOAD, DELETE, UPDATE, REVISE 
};
```

I would like to customize Eclipse Indigo formatter to do something like this:

```
private enum Operation {
                SAVE, 
                LOAD, 
                DELETE, 
                UPDATE, 
                REVISE 
};
```

I could not find any option suitable for my needs, what am I missing? Or is not possible at all with this version of IDE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under *Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter*, edit the active formatting profile, and set the *Line wrapping policy* for *Line Wrapping > 'enum' declaration > Constants* to *Wrap all elements, every element on a new line*.

Comment: In case anyone is having trouble with this... If you find that the enums are not placed on individual lines as you would expect, you may need to look at the "Settings for constants" options at the bottom of the page and check "Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width".